# Cannot tether iPhone under Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, tethering

I'm trying to connect to the Internet via my iPhone (**Ubuntu 11.04 32bit**).

**I installed all necessary packages** (`ipteth-utils`, `ifuse`, `libimobiledevice`, `usbmixd`, `gtkpod`…)

After that I connect my iphone to computer, trying to connect to iPhone network BUT it is not happening.

I did not have this problem in previous versions (9....10.10), and I know other people with the same problem.

Comment: Which iPhone do you have? Afaik the current iOS on iPhone4 and iPad can't be accessed.

Comment: I have iPhone 3GS with 4.2.1 firmware jailbraked

Answer (score 1):

A temporary work-around you can use is tether via the iphone bluetooth connection with the `blueman` package (that's what I've been doing in Maverick):

Open your terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

Then, activate your iphone's internet sharing via bluetooth, and using blueman pair it as an access point connection.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. but I am trying to pair my iphone via bluetooth (blueman) and I can connect...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how to pair your iPhone as an access point, here is how I did it. I first paired my iPhone with my computer using the Bluetooth icon (on the right part of the top panel). Then, I called blueman-assistant from the terminal to use my iPhone as an access point. I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it, but it worked.

Comment: When I am trying to pair my iphone to computer in blueman application the "pair" button is disabled